# Two .click methods interfering with each other?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two .click methods and i'm not sure why they will only work  in the absence of each other.

The code:

## 1 Responsible for sliding and hiding content

```
 var clickAction = function(){
        settings.tabHandle.click(function(event){
            if (obj.hasClass('open')) {
                slideIn();
            } else {
                slideOut();
            }
        });

        clickScreenToClose();
    };
```

## 2 Responsible for selectively reloading a div

```
$(
function(){
    var jContent = $( "#simplecart_items" );
    $( "a" ).click(
        function( objEvent ){
            var jLink = $( this );
            jContent.load( jLink.attr( "href" ) );
            return( false );                    
        }
        );

}
);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `$( "a" ).click(` is very general and could easily be mixed up. Please add your markup. Where do you define `settings.tabHandle`?

Comment: Are you getting console errors?

Comment: I'd suppose the `return false` in one click handler is preventing the other click handler from being triggered.

Comment: @jtheman You're correct, the full code is kind of long: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749856/allow-only-1-slideout-at-a-time

Comment: @Blazemonger No console errors, just not being able to click the first piece of code with the second present

Comment: And the docs to back up @Blazemonger - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: @Blazemonger Sweet, thanks for the direction. I used the alternative e.preventDefault(); instead of return (false); and both methods work.

Comment: @Sumo Thanks! doc link was great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing return( false );  in number 2 with objEvent.preventDefault();

[jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Event handlers in jQuery can prevent bubbling using a return value of false, or by calling these methods on the event object: event.preventDefault(), event.stopPropagation(), and event.stopImmediatePropagation()

event.preventDefault() stops the browser from performing it's default action for the event, e.g. form submit, navigation...

event.stopPropagation() stops jQuery from calling handlers attached to nodes further up the DOM.  Handlers attached at the same level will still be called.

event.stopImmediatePropagation() stops all handlers from being called.

Returning false from an event handler automatically calls event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault()

Comment: Thanks Patrick, that's exactly what I ended up doing. Worked like a charm. Info is much appreciated!